# ASP.Net core Model's date property is blank in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I have a Razor pages web app and one of the models' is for colleague info and includes their date of birth.

When I look at the scaffolded pages for a colleague, the Date of Birth field is populated in the details page but not the edit page.

Images below will show what I mean.

Here is the Details page

[image: Colleague Detail Page]

And here is the Edit page

[image: Colleague Edit Page]

As you will know, as the Edit page is blank, If I change another field e.g. Staff Position and save, the DOB for the colleague becomes null.

As I say the pages are from the EF Core scaffolding so I believe the HTML for the form should be correct.

Edit Page HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Colleague.DateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Colleague.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Colleague.DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Colleague is a bind Property of the Colleague model in the Page Model. ALl other fields, as seen in the image populate fine.

### Update

As I say it is using Model Binding

```cs
[BindProperty]
public Colleague Colleague { get; set; }
```

OnPost

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Attach(Colleague).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                selectedBranch = Colleague.BranchID;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ColleagueExists(Colleague.ColleagueID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("../BranchColleagues", new { id = selectedBranch });
        }
```

```cs
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: The Edit form is correctly populated initially? And after you save a change that one date field is null? Is the record's column on the database also null? Please show us enough code to reproduce this scenario.

Comment: Hi @Jasen I have added the OnPost to show what is being run on save. As for your question about the DB record. Yes it will overwrite. So in the image shown the details page has a D.O.B and this is in the DB also. If I save on the edit page without filling in the D.O.B, the record will update to being null for the D.O.B in the DB

Comment: I have previously encounter this problem. After adding ```type="datetime-local"``` into the ```<input>``` that is date time, it does populate. As what I know, this happens as the date format (utc or something) is incompatible.

Comment: Okay not sure the issue now. I just double checked the model and decided to test by commenting out this annotation

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Commenting that out has solved the issue. the edit page now shows the D.O.B and it is in local format e.g. dd/MM/yyyy whereas as you imagine, for the DB it is stored as yyyy-MM-dd . Can anyone see an issue with the annotation and why it would now work without it?

Comment: I tried the suggestion @GanHJ but the field was still blank after the edit.

Comment: What do you mean by *"whereas as you imagine, for the DB it is stored as yyyy-MM-dd"*? What's the **type** of the model property? Isn't it `DateTime` and stored as such in the database (i.e. typed value, hence no formatting)?

Comment: @IvanStoev I should have shared the model property to begin with. I have added it now but the model property is a Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am placing my quick fix solution as the question has been empty now for a month.

By removing this annotation from the POCO class:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

The date value now appears in the edit form as required.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. It works while I use `.Value` in input tag

```
<input asp-for="Colleague.DateOfBirth.Value" class="form-control" />
```